# How to change css properties on hover parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have this table:

```
<table>
  <tr><td class="momdad"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> Hello </td><td> Mom </td></tr>
  <tr><td class="momdad"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> Hello </td><td> Dad </td></tr>
</table>
```

And I want to show that Icon on class "momdad" hover, because is actually hidden, as you can see in this css:

```
i{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Is possible to make something like this?:

```
.momdad:hover{
    i{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

much more simple just try

```
.momdad:hover i {
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

example here:

```css
.momdad i {
  background-color: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.momdad:hover i {
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class="momdad"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'>icon</i> Hello </td><td> Mom </td></tr>
  <tr><td class="momdad"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'>icon</i> Hello </td><td> Dad </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors can be used by chaining the hierachy of the elements you want to select. For example:

`div a i` will select an `i`-element inside an `a`-element inside a `div`-element.

For your code, this would be the proper selector: `.momdad i`. Note that this will select ALL `i` inside `.momdad`, not just the direct child element. Use `.momdad > i` to only select the direct child. Further explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible to display child element on hover of parent element

```css
i{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.momdad:hover i{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr><td class="momdad"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> Hello </td><td> Mom </td></tr>
  <tr><td class="momdad"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> Hello </td><td> Dad </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's a shame that the other way around is still to be implemented

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible with pure css:

```
.momdad:hover i{visibility :visible }
```

With css when you hover on an element, you can affect that element itself or its children or next siblings and their children.

```css
span {
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 20px;
}
div:hover span,
div:hover ~ div span {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: You're right, I was with mobile when I post this answer, You can see my other answers, I always tried to include explanation.

Comment: I have only judged based on the content of your answer, but please if you will have time take the opportunity to edit it as per mentioned earlier.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: I will add some explanation to my answer as soon as possible.